# Error in using crispy form in django when i created signup from

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

In template /home/vivekdevkar/Desktop/code/Django/social_media/socialenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap4/uni_form.html, error at line 8

Comment: Can you provide some more context please ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `'crispy_forms'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` module?
Also, add `'CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'` in `settings.py` file.